# Validate And Submit Form For Google Drive

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I created a form for uploading files to my Google Drive.

Now I need to validate and submit my form. So i want to validate the inputs **first**, and **then** submit, but i can't do it.. When clicking "Upload" both things happen at the same time. Could somebody help me?

HTML:

```
<div>
<form name= "myForm" id="myForm">
<label><b>Name</b></label>
<input id="id1" type="text" name="myName" placeholder="Name.." required />
<label><b>Email</b></label>
<input id="id1" type="email" name="myEmail" placeholder="Email.." required />
<label><b>Tel</b></label>
<input id="id1" type="tel" name="myTel" placeholder="Tel.." required />
<input id="id1" type="file" name="myFile" required />
<button id="button" onclick="myFunction();">Upload</button>
</form>
</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>

function myFunction() {
    var upload = this.value='Uploading..';
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded).uploadFiles(this.parentNode);    
    return false;
    var inpObj = document.getElementById("id1");
    if (inpObj.checkValidity() == false) {
        document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = inpObj.validationMessage; return; 
    } else {
        document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = upload; 
    } 
}

function fileUploaded(status) {
    document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
}

</script>
```

Also, here is Server.gs:

```
function doGet(e) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html');
}

function uploadFiles(form) {

    try {

        var dropbox = "Videos";
        var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

        if (folders.hasNext()) {
            folder = folders.next();
        } else {
            folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
        }

        var blob = form.myFile;    
        var file = folder.createFile(blob);    
        file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + "|" + form.myName + "|" + form.myTitle + "|" + form.myEmail);

        return "Success.";

    } catch (error) {

        return error.toString();

    }

}
```

Comment: Since it seems you don't actualy need the form to be submited move button outside the form, and why there is "return false;" after google.script.run... it will never get to if(inpObj.checkValidity()... statement

Comment: I deleted the "return false;" after google.script.run..., but when i move the button outside the form it doesn't validate/submit anymore.

Comment: Why do you need to submit the form if everything is already on the server through google.script.run.with....? Which also means the validation is happening after everything was already sent. So google.script.ru.... should be last thing in myFunction()

Comment: I need to validate the form before submit. When i move google.script.ru.... to the end of myFunction() validation happens, but if the inputs are valid it doesn't submit/upload the attached file to my Google Drive.

Comment: try document.getElementById("myForm").submit(); after google.script.ru....

Comment: Didn't work .. It still validates and doesn't submit.